# Подгрузка изображений автоматически

Tags: изображения, css

Сейчас ситуация такая. На сайте есть черно-белые изображения. При наведении на них срабатывает событие hover и вместо нее загружается цветной аналог. Но на компьютерах с медленным интернет-соединением, заметна подгрузка картинки. Можно ли как-то автоматически подгружать эти цветные картинки заранее?

Знаю что можно сделать на одной картинке 2 варианта, и просто при наведении сменять координаты. Но просто не охота сейчас склеивать все эти изображения. Поэтому спрашиваю, как можно выйти из этой ситуации?

Comment: Перед `</body>` вставьте невидимый `div` и грузите картинки туда. Уровень сложности "newbie", так сказать)

Не знаю как сейчас у хромушки - он не любит кэшировать, во всем остальном это сработает.

Еще можно психануть и написать 

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('html *').trigger('mouseover').trigger('mouseout');
    });

` - `это по воробьям атомной бомбой, но тоже будет работать :)

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $('html *').trigger('mouseover').trigger('mouseout');
}); не сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS&HTML:

```
<img src="normal.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='hover.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='normal.jpg'"/>
<script>
  var img = new Image();
  img.src='hover.jpg';
</script>
```

CSS:

```
a#itm1 {background: url('normal.jpg')}
a#itm1:hover {background: url('hover.jpg')}
```

Все зависит от того где и как вы делаете этот rollover. Возможны другие варианты...

Comment: Гуглить можно по словам "preload images", например.

Comment: Этот скрипт разве не будет подгружать картинки после наведения?

Comment: попробуйте. картинки будут грузиться сразу все.